# jquery mobile doesn't load file when button click event

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

My jquery mobile layout has a navigation bar that contains both buttons. When click on a button, another file (html5+jquery-mobile) should be loaded and is not because doesn't call related javascripts! However, if I load that file individualy, works as charm. 
External link call is not a solution because transitions will then be missed. How to solve it? Thank you.

file call (jquery)

```
$("#head").append("<a href='"+linkIz+".html' data-role='button'  data-transition='flip'  data-icon="+iconoIz+" >"+textoIz+"</a>");
```

Comment: How are you calling the other file? Through changePage? Can you post the code of your other file? Make sure your other file javascript code is within the <div data-role="page">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple solution. Place all of your site's JS in an external file, then include that file in every HTML document. That way all the JS for the whole site will be available no matter what page the user landed on your site or if the user refreshes the page.

Your file could include this to put navigation bars on each page as it is initialized:

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', function () {
    $(this).children('[data-role="header"]').append("<a href='" + linkIz + ".html' data-role='button'  data-transition='flip'  data-icon=" + iconoIz + " >" + textoIz + "</a>");
});
```

Make sure to use event delegation since you won't know exactly when any specific page is in the DOM.

Also I'm assuming that `#head` is the `data-role="header"` element for a page, if this is the case then you should change that to `.head` (class instead of ID) because you can have multiple pages in the DOM at once, so all IDs for the entire website have to be unique. I generally give each `data-role="page"` element an Id, then I use classes to get more specific within pages, this assures I'm not creating multiple elements with the same ID that can be in the DOM at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to refresh the jQM functionality on your page so that it knows to bind the `a` tag (link) by ajax.  Did you already try something like this?

```
$("#head").trigger('refresh');
```

This would be after you append the new link.

Hope this helps.